# Mysql query error when trying to extract from two different tables with where clause

Tags: php, mysql

I am not able to retrieve query result when I am trying to extract data from two different table where column data matches(b/w column of first table and column of second table)

I used following 2 methods:

```
 SELECT a.*, FROM `table1` a, `table2` b
 WHERE a.`synonyms` in (b.`synonyms`);
```

or

```
SELECT a.*, FROM `table1` a, `table2` b
WHERE a.`synonyms`=b.`synonyms`;
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` where `synonyms` in (SELECT `synonyms`from `table2`WHERE 1);
```

First Query showing error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `table1` a, `table2` b  WHERE' at line 1
```

---

Second query is running long time and then at the end displaying nothing except:
show your query.

What mistake am I making here?

PS: tabel1 and table both having synonyms column (value of synonym is in varchar). around 300k synonyms(eg:gene name) are there in table1. table2 have around 5000 synonyms which also exsist in table1. I want to extract those 5000 from table1 with extra information it contain.

```
    SELECT * FROM `table1` where `synonyms` in ('synonym1','synonym2','synonym3','synonym4');
```

Comment: `SELECT a.*,`  remove `,`

Comment: I removed and tried all method but nothing is working in this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
 SELECT a.*, FROM
```

to

```
SELECT a.* FROM
```

plus use join in your query like

```
SELECT a.* FROM `table1` a join `table2` b on (a.synonyms=b.synonyms);
```

Comment: after executing            SELECT a.* FROM `table1` a join `table2` b on (a.synonyms=b.synonyms); what i am getting in results is "Show query box".    Is there any problem with numerical data or varchar data ?

Comment: i hve trid this in my situation it works for me, try (a.synonyms like b.synonyms) instead of (a.synonyms=b.synonyms)

Answer (score 1):

Change     `SELECT a.*, FROM` to `SELECT a.* FROM`

Comment: Hi,thnks   i removed comma, still i am not getting any output (run time aorund 10 min), not even any error , its redirecting it to main database page after completion.

Answer (score 0):

In the second query you should define WHERE... = 'something'.

The right syntax is WHERE column_name operator value;

In first query you should remove comma like pointed already.